# I lost my blender render

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I left my PC running over night for rendering. Blender crashed for some reason and I lost my render. It doesn't show up if I press <kbd>F11</kbd>. Is there way to recover it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to recover the rendering that was completed before the crash. The render data is held in Blender's internal memory and is lost when Blender closes.

If you are rendering an animation, I strongly recommend rendering your individual frames as .PNG first, then compositing the individual frames into a film using Blender's Film Editing tools, after all of the frames have been rendered.

[image]

This way, if you suffer a crash while rendering, all of the frames rendered *before* the crash will be saved locally in your PC. You can resume rendering from the frame where the crash happened.

If you are finding you need to leave your PC running overnight to render a single frame, you may want to consider lowering your sample count and adding some more aggressive denoising:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid to lose your render after it is finished and your computer crashed you could use an addon called [Autosave-Render](https://github.com/ICarryTheDustOfAJourney/Autosave-Render)